# Force mocha to always show "diffs"... even for passing tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, logging, mocha.js

So, upon failing a test, `mocha` will display the "expected" and "actual" values of your assertion, i.e...

```
AssertionError: expected 3 to be 4
  actual expected
  3      4
```

Useful.  *However*, when all is going well, and your tests are passing.. no such info is displayed.  Regardless of whether or not you supply the `--inline-diffs` option, you simply get...

```
 ✓ your goddamn test passed

 1 passing (69ms)
```

**Is it possibly to cajole, persuade, or coax `mocha` into displaying the former's more descriptive details of the test's "intermediate values", *even if* the results pass?** Like...

```
 ✓ your goddamn test passed (result was 4)
```

Comment: How is it supposed to come up with `result was 4` string? There can be more than one assertion in the spec, not each of them can be described in human-readable form. It may be possible to generate report text *somehow* with custom reporter, but a proper approach is to just give tests meaningful names for starters. 'your goddamn test' could be named 'should be equal to 4' or so.